# ALB Ingress annotation - how to add tags for listener rules?

Tags: kubernetes, aws-application-load-balancer, ingress-controller

I've successfully deployed an ALB Ingress Controller in my Amazon EKS cluster, and it's performing well in creating ALB groups with associated rules.

However, I'm currently facing a challenge in specifying tags for individual listener rules. While I've discovered an option to add tags to the ALB itself using the `alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/tags` annotation, I couldn't find a direct method to tag the individual listener rules.

Is there a way to add tags to listener rules created by the AWS ALB Ingress Controller? Any insights or guidance on achieving this would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Tagging each individual rule is currently not supported. You can tag using CLI like: `aws elbv2 add-tags --resource-arns <rule arn> --tags 'key=<name>,value=<something>'`